# Supported C-States on Intel 10th Gen W-1290P

Tags: linux, hardware, intel

I am running a machine that I recently upgraded to a [Intel 10th Gen Xeon W-1290P Comet Lake CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/199336/intel-xeon-w-1290p-processor-20m-cache-3-70-ghz.html). The CPU is really similar to the normal desktop i9-10900k.

On this machine, I am running Proxmox. I am using kernel 5.11.

```
root@server:~# uname -a
Linux server 5.11.21-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.11.21-1~bpo10 (Wed, 02 Jun 2021 11:34:45 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After the upgrade (from a E3-1245 v6) my system is using considerably more energy even when idling. I tried to investigate what is going on and found, that my system never enters any C-States deeper than C3.

Trying to verify which C-States are supported gives me different results.

```
root@server:~# cat /sys/module/intel_idle/parameters/max_cstate
9
```

Here, my system seems to think it supports up to C9.

```
root@server:~# cpupower idle-info
CPUidle driver: intel_idle
CPUidle governor: menu
analysiere CPU 0:

Number of idle states: 4
Available idle states: POLL C1_ACPI C2_ACPI C3_ACPI
POLL:
Flags/Description: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
Latency: 0
Usage: 1012041
Duration: 3293515
C1_ACPI:
Flags/Description: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x0
Latency: 1
Usage: 1340146
Duration: 215843217
C2_ACPI:
Flags/Description: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x33
Latency: 151
Usage: 949495
Duration: 949112994
C3_ACPI:
Flags/Description: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x60
Latency: 1034
Usage: 315636
Duration: 1552349782
```

Running `cpupower idle-info` shows that only 4 states are supported, and instead of the states I would expect `C1`, `C2`, `C3` and so on the states are named `C1_ACPI` and so on.

I verified that my system uses `intel_idle` as the CPUidle driver, and `intel_pstate` as the scaling driver.

```
root@server:~# cpupower frequency-info
analysiere CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  Folgende CPUs laufen mit der gleichen Hardware-Taktfrequenz: 0
  Die Taktfrequenz folgender CPUs werden per Software koordiniert: 0
  Maximale Dauer eines Taktfrequenzwechsels:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  Hardwarebedingte Grenzen der Taktfrequenz: 800 MHz - 5.30 GHz
  mÃ¶gliche Regler: performance powersave
  momentane Taktik: die Frequenz soll innerhalb 800 MHz und 5.30 GHz.
                    liegen. Der Regler "powersave" kann frei entscheiden,
                    welche Taktfrequenz innerhalb dieser Grenze verwendet wird.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 4.90 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Why is my system not supporting deeper C-States, like C6? Is there anything I can do to change this?

Comment: Did you figure this out, by any chance?